# "Session expired" not working in Wicket

Tags: session, wicket, wicket-1.5

When the user of my wicket application loses their session (e.g. session expires), links on the pages they are seeing, and form submissions, just show the user the startpage. Instead, if the right result cannot be displayed, I would expect Wicket to show its "session expired" error message.

For example, the startpage displays some data. You enter a query into a search field, and click on the submit button. You would expect to see either your filtered results, or an error (session expired), but instead Wicket just silently creates a new session and shows the startpage, which is the results without the filter. That looks like a bug ("filter doesn't work!").

For example, if you go the page https://login.firstbird.eu/, then delete the JSESSIONID cookie, and then click on the "forgot your password" link, then you'd expect the "forgot password" page to be displayed but instead the startpage is displayed again. (I know this could be solved with a bookmarkable link, but there are other situations which rely on session and page information that can't be solved with a bookmarkable link.)

There are no serialization errors in the log, but I think that wouldn't matter anyway. There are still going to be times when the session expires (e.g. timeout), no matter if the session and pages were serializable or not.

I think I first noticed this functionality in Wicket 1.5; I'm pretty certain this worked in Wicket 1.4.

This looks like a bug in Wicket to me. Am I wrong? Am I misunderstanding the intention of Wicket here? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting whether to show the PageExpiredPage or to recreate the current page:
https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/2de1284a589f7862133bb2c2166bf8563268d252/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/IPageSettings.java#L67-L77

Most people prefer to show the fresh instance instead of losing the context and find their way back. That's why this is the default.